# Having an object in a list know statistical information about that list

Tags: c#

For the sake of argument I have Person Objects

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to have a List  or something similar where each person can tell if they are older or younger than the average age. (Ideally I want to say top 10% and bottom 10%) but I will settle for over under median.

Is there a way to do this?

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
//Fill People
foreach(var person in people)
{ 
  if (person.TopTenPercent)
  { 
     Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
  }
}
```

Thanks 
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you should have the list or something else encapsulate this information ([SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and all that). So say that you have

```
class People : IEnumerable<Person> {
    public double MedianAge { get; }
    // etc.
}
```

Then you would say

```
foreach(var person in people.Where(p => p.Age >= people.MedianAge)) {
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

For the general case you can have a `PercentileAge` method on your `People` class:

```
public double PercentileAge(double percentile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq:

1. Calculate the average (`.Average()`-Extension method)
2. Compute percentual distance to the average age
3. Select specified range

Comment: Knowing the average does not help you compute the percentiles.

Answer (score 0):

Make a personlist that adds itself as a reference to the person so that the person can query the list's contents/stats